Error when building a substrate node template with multiple balances pallet instances configured
Im getting the following Substrate Error when configuring more than 1 balances
 note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `RuntimeCall: From<BalancesCall<_, _>>` found in the `my_node` crate:
            - impl From<<pallet_balances::pallet::Pallet<my_node::Runtime, Instance2> as frame_support::dispatch::Callable<my_node::Runtime>>::RuntimeCall> for RuntimeCall;
            - impl From<<pallet_balances::pallet::Pallet<my_node::Runtime> as frame_support::dispatch::Callable<my_node::Runtime>>::RuntimeCall> for RuntimeCall;
    = note: required for `BalancesCall<_, _>` to implement `Into<RuntimeCall>`


Balances configuration
pub use pallet_balances::Call as BalancesCall;

impl pallet_balances::Config for Runtime {
    type Balance = Balance;
    type DustRemoval = ();
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type ExistentialDeposit = ConstU128<EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT>;
    type AccountStore = System;
    type MaxLocks = MaxLocks;
    type MaxReserves = MaxReserves;
    type ReserveIdentifier = [u8; 8];
    type WeightInfo = ();
    type FreezeIdentifier = ();
    type MaxFreezes = ();
    type HoldIdentifier = ();
    type MaxHolds = ConstU32<1>;
}

impl pallet_balances::Config<pallet_balances::Instance2> for Runtime {
    type Balance = Balance;
    type DustRemoval = ();
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type ExistentialDeposit = ConstU128<EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT>;
    type AccountStore = System;
    type MaxLocks = MaxLocks;
    type MaxReserves = MaxReserves;
    type ReserveIdentifier = [u8; 8];
    type WeightInfo = ();
    type FreezeIdentifier = ();
    type MaxFreezes = ();
    type HoldIdentifier = ();
    type MaxHolds = ConstU32<1>;
}


Construct runtime code
construct_runtime!(
    pub struct Runtime
    where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system,

        Timestamp: pallet_timestamp,
        Balances: pallet_balances,
        EthBalances: pallet_balances::<Instance2>,
         
    }
);

code in node\src\benchmarking.rs
impl frame_benchmarking_cli::ExtrinsicBuilder for TransferKeepAliveBuilder {
    fn pallet(&self) -> &str {
        "balances"
    }

    fn extrinsic(&self) -> &str {
        "transfer_keep_alive"
    }

    fn build(&self, nonce: u32) -> std::result::Result<OpaqueExtrinsic, &'static str> {
        let acc = Sr25519Keyring::Bob.pair();
        let extrinsic: OpaqueExtrinsic = create_benchmark_extrinsic(
            self.client.as_ref(),
            acc,
            BalancesCall::transfer_keep_alive {
                dest: self.dest.clone().into(),
                value: self.value.into(),
            }
            .into(),
            nonce,
        )
        .into();

        Ok(extrinsic)
    }
}

Ho to fix this error and define tranfer_keep_alive for multiple balances inmstances?


You can pass generic config and instance like this:
let eth_balance_call = BalancesCall::<Runtime, pallet_balances::Instance2>::transfer_keep_alive { .. };

